NXLogs not receiving logs
I'm trying to set up NXlog CE to receive logs from 3 devices and write them to a JSON File.
Its working for one IP, but not the rest.
Using Wireshark I can see that the logs are reaching the device on UDP 514, but NXLogs wont paste them to the JSON file.
Here the snippet of the code:
`
define ROOT     C:\nxlog
define CERTDIR  %ROOT%\cert
define CONFDIR  %ROOT%\conf\nxlog.d
define LOGDIR   %ROOT%\data

include %CONFDIR%\\*.conf
define LOGFILE  %LOGDIR%\nxlog.log
LogFile %LOGFILE%

Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir  %ROOT%\data
Pidfile   %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir  %ROOT%\data

<Extension _syslog>
    Module      xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Extension _charconv>
    Module      xm_charconv
    AutodetectCharsets iso8859-2, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32
</Extension>

<Extension _exec>
    Module      xm_exec
</Extension>

<Extension json>
    Module    xm_json
</Extension>

<Extension _fileop>
    Module      xm_fileop

    # Check the size of our log file hourly, rotate if larger than 5MB
    <Schedule>
        Every   1 hour
        Exec    if (file_exists('%LOGFILE%') and \
                   (file_size('%LOGFILE%') >= 5M)) \
                    file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
    </Schedule>

    # Rotate our log file every week on Sunday at midnight
    <Schedule>
        When    @weekly
        Exec    if file_exists('%LOGFILE%') file_cycle('%LOGFILE%', 8);
    </Schedule>
</Extension>

# Collecting event log

<Input in1>
    Module     im_udp
    Host       IP1
#    Port       514    # Assuming default syslog port
</Input>


<Input in2>
    Module     im_udp
    Host       IP2
#    Port       514    # Assuming default syslog port
</Input>

<Input in3>
    Module     im_udp
    Host       IP3
#    Port       514    # Assuming default syslog port
</Input>
 
# Output 
<Output out>
    Module    om_file
    File      "C:\Syslogs\Outlog.json"
    Exec      to_json();
</Output>

# Connect input 'in' to output 'out'
<Route udp_to_file>
    Path       in1, in2, in3 => out
</Route>`

Am I missing something?
THanks.
Tried with nxlog install on a windows device.
Also tried to do it on Linux (Virtualbox) but still not working.

You may want to try with Host 0.0.0.0 so that it listens on all interfaces:
<Input in3>
    Module     im_udp
    Host       0.0.0.0
#    Port       514    # Assuming default syslog port
</Input>

Host is the local address where it accepts connections. It's not the IP of your remote syslog devices.

Thanks for the reply, That is the configuration I have on the Linux version, but it doesn't work.  Tried to changed it on Windows and got the error: 'ERROR failed to start im_udp; couldn't bind udp socket to 0.0.0.0:514; Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'

"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" - You already have another instance of nxlog or another service running that is listening on that port.
